Wordpress: 301 redirects add UTF-8 characters
during a site audit with ahrefs, we discovered some double slashes in URL issues.
Strangely for 301 redirects the UTF-8 charaters:
-%E2%80%9E
-%E2%80%9C
are added.
Example:
https://website.com/content/%E2%80%9Ehttps://website.com%E2%80%9C
This happens to all redirects.
I am out of ideas.
Anyone able to help, to get rid of this issue?
The only plug-in we use for redirects is RankMath. No redirects configured.
RankMath Redirect settings:
Debug Redirections: off
Fallback Behaviour: Default 404
Redirection Type: 301
Auto Post Redirect: on
This is the current htaccess:
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>`

WP Permalink Settings:

Post name (https://website.com/sample-post/


Those codes are UTF-8 for „ and “. Sounds like some code that's creating those URLs has those superfluous quote characters somewhere.

@deceze yes seems like it, i'm not very firm with htaccess rules. Is there by chance any to prevent using this characters for redirections?
